# How to merge objects into one string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Say i have an object like this

````
```
{
  "ListOfStudents": {
    "-LTzCztVLA0PW-duF-3e": {
      "StudentInfo": {
        "csvTestFile": {
          "2018-12-18": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-18",
            "attendanceStatus": "present"
          },
          "2018-12-19": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-19",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          },
          "2018-12-20": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-20",
            "attendanceStatus": "present"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "-LTz15VLA0PW-duF-123": {
      "StudentInfo": {
        "csvTestFile": {
          "2018-12-18": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-18",
            "attendanceStatus": "present"
          },
          "2018-12-19": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-19",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          },
          "2018-12-20": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-20",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "-LTz15VL515W-duF-163": {
      "StudentInfo": {
        "csvTestFile": {
          "2018-12-18": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-18",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          },
          "2018-12-19": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-19",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          },
          "2018-12-20": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-20",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```
````

***Here's my code***

```
const names = 'Albert,John,Alex';

saveCSVFile(data) {
const { classUID } = data;
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

const student = [];

firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/ClassAttendance/${classUID}/ListOfStudents`)
  .on('value', snapshot1 => {
    snapshot1.forEach(child => {
      student.push(child.val().StudentInfo);

      const keys = Object.keys(child.val().StudentInfo.csvTestFile);
      const dates = keys.map(key => child.val().StudentInfo.csvTestFile[key]);
      console.log(dates);
    });
  });
}
```

[Here's the console log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alKvR.png)

What i wanted is to merge **'attendanceStatus'** into one string but for every first object i want to put each names in the string, and for every last object i want to put **'\n'** on it and a **,** (comma) for each attendanceStatus.

Expected Final Output in String:

> 'Albert,present,absent,present\n
>
> John,present,absent,absent\n
>
> Alex,absent,absent,absent\n'

or may be the output would be like this

> 'Albert,present,absent,present\nJohn,present,absent,absent\nAlex,absent,absent,absent\n'

I have been thinking on how to do this for a week, but no luck. Please help

Comment: Please show an attempt at solving your problem and share your data as text rather than an image.

Comment: ok ill edit my post

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation using map instead:

```js
let list = {
        "-LTzCztVLA0PW-duF-3e": {
          "StudentInfo": {
            "csvTestFile": {
              "2018-12-18": {
                "attendanceDate": "2018-12-18",
                "attendanceStatus": "present"
              },
              "2018-12-19": {
                "attendanceDate": "2018-12-19",
                "attendanceStatus": "absent"
              },
              "2018-12-20": {
                "attendanceDate": "2018-12-20",
                "attendanceStatus": "present"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "-LTz15VLA0PW-duF-123": {
          "StudentInfo": {
            "csvTestFile": {
              "2018-12-18": {
                "attendanceDate": "2018-12-18",
                "attendanceStatus": "present"
              },
              "2018-12-19": {
                "attendanceDate": "2018-12-19",
                "attendanceStatus": "absent"
              },
              "2018-12-20": {
                "attendanceDate": "2018-12-20",
                "attendanceStatus": "absent"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "-LTz15VL515W-duF-163": {
          "StudentInfo": {
            "csvTestFile": {
              "2018-12-18": {
                "attendanceDate": "2018-12-18",
                "attendanceStatus": "absent"
              },
              "2018-12-19": {
                "attendanceDate": "2018-12-19",
                "attendanceStatus": "absent"
              },
              "2018-12-20": {
                "attendanceDate": "2018-12-20",
                "attendanceStatus": "absent"
              }
            }
          }
        }
     }
     
    const names = 'Albert,John,Alex';

    let resultString = Object.keys(list).map((l, index) => {
      let csvTestFiles = list[l].StudentInfo.csvTestFile;
      return Object.keys(csvTestFiles).map((i, innerIndex) => {
        let str = innerIndex === 0 ? `${names.split(',')[index]},` : '';
        return str + csvTestFiles[i].attendanceStatus;
      }).join(',');
    }).join('\\n').concat('\\n'); // replace with '\n' if you want the new line instead, concat is just appending last '\n' to the string
    console.log(resultString);
```

Comment: Hi @muhammad, I have a new question and edited my post for a better explanation. How can i add the names of the students in the new generated string from your solution? Let say, I have a string 'const names = 'Albert,John,Alex', i want each of these names to merge from the first place of the new generated string?

Comment: Unfortunately your solution replace the first attendanceStatus with the name. If you try to Run the code snipper, you will see the name and only 2 attendanceStatus for each. :(

Comment: my bad, updated the code with name and all attendanceStatus.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for but I hope this gets you on the right track.

```js
let list = {
    "-LTzCztVLA0PW-duF-3e": {
      "StudentInfo": {
        "csvTestFile": {
          "2018-12-18": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-18",
            "attendanceStatus": "present"
          },
          "2018-12-19": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-19",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          },
          "2018-12-20": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-20",
            "attendanceStatus": "present"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "-LTz15VLA0PW-duF-123": {
      "StudentInfo": {
        "csvTestFile": {
          "2018-12-18": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-18",
            "attendanceStatus": "present"
          },
          "2018-12-19": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-19",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          },
          "2018-12-20": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-20",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "-LTz15VL515W-duF-163": {
      "StudentInfo": {
        "csvTestFile": {
          "2018-12-18": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-18",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          },
          "2018-12-19": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-19",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          },
          "2018-12-20": {
            "attendanceDate": "2018-12-20",
            "attendanceStatus": "absent"
          }
        }
      }
    }
 },
 result = "";
 for(let s in list) {
  let c = list[s].StudentInfo.csvTestFile; //get the object with the dates
  for(let d in c) {
     result += c[d].attendanceStatus + ','; //add the status with a comma
  }
  result = result.slice(0, result.length -1); //remove the trailling comma
   result += '\n'; //add a newline char for every student
 }
 console.log(result); //yay
```

Comment: OMG, i think my problem is solved now. Thank you very much. The slice(0,test.length) is all i needed. Thank you again. I hope you become a millionaire someday

Comment: Hi, I have a new question and edited my post for a better explanation. How can i add the names of the students in the new generated string from your solution? Let say, I have a string 'const names = 'albert1,albert2,albert3', i want each of these names to merge from the first place of the new generated string?